# Ubuntu 16.04 keeps freezing and not responding at all

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit

I use Ubuntu 16.04 amd64. now I can't use it as after logging in it starts freezing and I have to shutdown my computer by the power button. I've noticed that the red indicator next to power button keeps indicate with non-stop. what must I do to make it work as it used to?

PS. I don't know what kind of log to include here

Comment: Is the red indicator the hard drive indicator?

Comment: @GamingWessel yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, Ubuntu is accessing the hard drive rapidly. The led blinks every time when the OS accesses the hard drive.

Not sure if this is the case but it seems like you have a really slow drive. If that is the case then this will work

Just boot into Ubuntu and wait a few minutes till the LED stops blinking. Then do what ever you want.

Be patient. Not sure if this will work though

Comment: I checked my hdd is ok. I'm thinking about kernel that must be problem

Comment: @Steve If you have another computer you could try flashing a usb stick with ubuntu, and see if it freezes.

Comment: @GamingWessel good thinking!!

Comment: I don't know how to do it(

Comment: @Steve follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/U-7chlCn6yk